# Can I have AmigaOS style "volume names" in zsh on my Mac?

Tags: mount, zsh, macos

On my Amiga back in the day, volumes had names, like `DF0:` for the floppy drive mount point. In the CLI you typed `DF0:` and you'd CD into the floppy drive mount point. You could also use it in path names, like `cat DF0:readme.txt` (memory a little hazy, hopefully I remember this right). You could create your own volume names. I could have added `Work:` to point to some folder of my choice and get there quickly.

It's a little similar I guess to how in Windows you can define `Z:` to point to some network location.

Has anyone come across a similar tool for zsh on the Mac?

I realise in Linux you could do something with bind mounts, like maybe create `/work` and then bind mount it to point at the real work folder. Might even get pretty far with just a symlink. But is there a true solution out there, complete with the `:` syntax?

(I don't know why, it might just be nostalgia, but I remember this system as feeling very intuitive and fast to work with.)

Comment: direct mapping between floppy/disk/partition of a disk and filesystem make more sense in Amga's day than nowdays. (a floppy would held a unique filesystem, a disk would be parted but W/O LVM or RAID). beside Amiga dies 11/5/1955  :(

Comment: Kind of still makes sense to be able to say `cp USB0:myfile.txt ~/` instead of figuring out where a USB stick ends up mounting. (Although for the purposes of this question I'm more specifically interested in the convenience of having a quick and easy `work:` alias or whatnot.)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, drive letters are awful, and one of the best things about unix filesystems is that everything is under just **one** tree hierarchy, and you can mount formatted block devices wherever you like.

But if that's what you want, symlinks would be the way to do it.

You can even make symlinks with colons in them, like `ln -s /path/ ~/amiga-like/DF0:`

or `ln -s /other/path/ ~/dos/Z:`

---

BTW, this is how [WINE](https://www.winehq.org) and Steam's [Proton](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/) make drive-letter symlinks in their wine prefixes.  e.g. if you run wine, look in `$WINEPREFIX/dosdevices`, and you'll see a symlink farm pointing to various subdirectories, like this:

```
$ ls -lF /var/games/steam2/steamapps/compatdata/414340/pfx/dosdevices/
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 10 Jul 31 23:42 c: -> ../drive_c/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 10 Aug  1 14:15 com1 -> /dev/ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 10 Aug  1 14:15 com2 -> /dev/ttyS1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 10 Aug  1 14:15 com3 -> /dev/ttyS2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas 10 Aug  1 14:15 com4 -> /dev/ttyS3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas  9 Jul 31 23:42 d:: -> /dev/sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas  8 Jul 31 23:42 e:: -> /dev/sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cas cas  1 Jul 31 23:42 z: -> //
```

(and, yes, that Z: symlink pointing to / is annoying.  I've already submitted a bug report about it.  valve's devs don't see any problem with giving every windows game full access to my linux filesystem from the root directory down instead of just the game's own directory and whatever else I might optionally choose to give access to).

Comment: The Amiga drive names were not as dreadful as MS-DOS ones: They could be more than one letter; they could refer to a device or to a disk (disk labels), if you specified a disk label, then the OS would ask the user to insert that disk (if not already inserted). There was a lot going for it. However, this question is about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this exact syntax. The colon is an ordinary character in file names; `DF0:readme.txt` is the file called `DF0:readme.txt` in the current directory. (Actually `:` is special in some contexts in zsh: it's how you can apply [history modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers). But this doesn't have the structure you want.)

You can define something similar with a tilde prefix rather than a colon infix. `~ALIAS` at the beginning of a path expands `ALIAS` as a [named directory](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories). This generalizes `~USERNAME` found in Bourne-style shells. You can define your own named directories (also called directory aliases) with [`hash -d`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash-1).

```
hash -d DF0=/Volumes/Floppy
cat ~DF0/readme.txt
```

If you want to change to a directory without having to type `cd`, make sure to have [`setopt auto_cd`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD) in your `.zshrc`, and just type the path to that directory. This is completely orthogonal to the way the directory path may have been abbreviated.

Comment: I suppose one could use the *dynamic named directory* feature to have `~[DF0:readme.txt]` expand to `/Volumes/Floppy/readme.txt` if one was so attached to using `:`s  there.

Comment: I'd be totally OK with `:` being ambiguous for these purposes. For example having to write ./DF0:readme.txt to access such a file in the CWD.